# How to avoid abuse of "restoring" in-app purchases to different devices?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a free app with a paid upgrade option. If I upgrade my app, then reinstall it, then upgrade again, I get a notification that I have already bought this upgrade with this Apple ID, so I can just re-upgrade the app for free. This is of course a nice feature for restoring upgrades, BUT...

What prevents a user from logging in with his Apple ID on different devices and choosing the upgrade option, thus downloading the upgrade for free to all these devices? For example, one user could do this on several devices belonging to his friends.

Help?

Comment: The fact that using two Apple IDs is a major pain in the ass and something that makes you want to burn down the Apple HQ should be a sufficient mechanism to prevent that.

Comment: I disagree in this case. The user only needs to log in briefly with the "upgraded" Apple ID and "restore" the upgrade, after which he can go back to using his normal Apple ID again, now with an upgraded app. This would only take a minute.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing stops them doing that. The same way a user can pay for apps from the app store, then login on friends iPhone and download it again.
As your In App Purchase should be available on that users other devices too, then this is normal behaviour.